# Redirect using .htaccess but should not show in address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I have a web project setup on Apache Web Server.

It's a Laravel project and files placed in /flex360/opera

Whenever I hit my domain, the project should execute from the folder /flex360/opera/public but the address bar should only show /flex360/opera

I tried multiple .htaccess solutions to achieve this but none seems to work.

This should have been standard solution but it's not working.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Apache Config

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/flex360/opera/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This gives Too Many Redirects error but I manually give public in address bar, it works

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=<domain>
RewriteRule ^ <domain>%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
```

Can someone provide me solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/` - that will never match, when the base URL path leading to that folder is `/flex360/opera/public/`. _That_ is the request URI you will have to check for.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. Can you please explain more?

Comment: You need to check against the _actual_ request URI - which won't be `/public/`, because that is _not_ the path to your app, from the domain root. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/flex360/opera/public/`

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, I tried this but it's not working. 

And my request URL is /public, What I want to execute is in Public folder.

Comment: How could your request URI possibly be just `/public`, when you say you want the browser address bar to show `/flex360/opera`? That makes no sense.